# How to modeling an alphabet monument from image reference?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I plan to make this letter monument in Blender, but I am confused how to make the exact same shape as that monument especially the curve shape on the alphabet. can anyone give me a little example

[image]

Comment: Try googling the statues details and "font". You might get lucky and obtain the font and add text objects.

Comment: Aside from finding that font, it seems that the proportional edit tool would be a big help, along with spin.

Comment: I would check out Oliver Villar's, "How to make a 3D Logo" on YouTube

Comment: i would like to made it from the beginning of the mesh so if i have similar problem in the future i wouldn't get trouble again

Comment: The font would be like getting plan front view, also for the sake of an answer, even if it isn't accepted, what is the name and location of the building / art installation.

Comment: I think modeling the sculptures with a bezier curve would be easiest.

Comment: I found some front views for you... Happy blending http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GmWP07uKQmU/VUNYP7M3bpI/AAAAAAAAFHI/AtH17G8DrPs/s1600/Jl.Braga.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the art installation (which is at the intersection of Naripan and [Braga Street, in Bandung, Indonesia](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g297704-d3257737-i180128476-Braga_Street-Bandung_West_Java_Java.html); (Geographical co-ordinates: -6.920010, 107.610142)) might be inspired by, or copied from a font, but I tend to think it a bit more likely that the realization of the shapes is done from scratch, as they might be in a logo. I know there are a number of tutorials on Youtube, and in other sources on using Blender to create a 3D logo. Do a search for "Blender 3D logo tutorial", and you should come up with several.

If, as I suspect, the glyphs in the image posted in the original question are custom designed for the sculpture, it would be useful to have some idea as to the scale of the elements. Reviewing a few of images I found in on-line sources, I infer from the ratio of the size of the people I see pictured in some of the images to the size of the elements, that the height of the individual elements in the installation are about 3 meters from the plane upon which they are installed, and the thickness of the wider strokes of the element are about .3 meters. I would use image editing software to make the heights of the elements, and the width of the wider strokes as nearly the same in each image as possible. I would model the individual elements using. Unless this is an assignment the exact dimensions of the model are required to conform to the exact proportions of the orginal, this may be a case where "close is good enough". In either case, the standard modeling techniques—start with a mesh primitive, and scale, translate (move), extrude, rotate, and subdivide as needed to create the elements—should be adequate to model the elements of the installation.

On the other hand, if the shapes of the letters were different so that one could select a font and use a text object as the basis for the model, there are tutorials on Youtube covering that, too. On example of such is at https://youtu.be/48L9YU1FKPU.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off designing your font objects in an illustration type of software like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or Adobe Illustrator.

It will be a lot easier to accomplish those intricate designs and tweak them to your liking using a bezier curve based workflow. Those applications are a lot more suitable and flexible for this kind of work.

Once you are done, you can then import your font objects into blender using SVG.

Inkscape Drawing
[image: Inkscape]

Imported into Blender
[image: Bezier K]

See here for more details https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53768/19307

Alternatively you can also use blender's built-in bezier curve objects and editing tools although they are admittedly less refined and harder to work with.

Comment: I think you can do it without inkscape. Just Use bezier curves to model the shape, then transform it into a mesh.

Comment: You can, no need to transform into mesh for most things. But as stated in the answer Bezier curve tools in Blender are a far less flexible and easy to use, that is why I suggested using one of the dedicated programs.

Comment: Blender ftw, all else is blasphemy