# How to soften the edges/faces of a solid?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, faces

(beginner)

If I have this:
[image]

How can i soften the edges in the following way?

[image]

It is very important for me to get Softness only along the XY axis, without changing the dimensions of the Z axis.
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60239/how-to-round-the-edges-of-this-object/60242#60242, also consider using a bezier curve object for this type of shape also consider using *Bezier Curve Objects* instead https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53762/how-can-i-smooth-the-edges-of-these-modelled-letters/53768#53768

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is select the left and right edge, as well as the top and bottom loop like so (make sure to do so while selecting edges, **not faces**):

[image]

Then, click <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up a tab on the right. Under *Transform*, set the mean crease to **1** like so:

[image]

Then, add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object:

[image]

And you're done, your model should look something like this:

[image]

The smoother you want the object to be, the higher the *View* and *Render* number in the modifier should be.